# Single javascript file vs MVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Im just getting into app development and it seems that the style is to use an MVC style of coding where you have an app.js, controller.js, and service.js and etc. All codepens I see are always a single HTML file plus a single js file. What is the difference between these two styles? It seems like building putting them all in a single js file would be more convenient but why would someone go through the trouble of splitting up the code?

Comment: you can read the very good article right one that topic : http://perfectionkills.com/refactoring-single-page-app/ Other than that, it is really a matter of preference. (for example Python framework `Bottle` will emphasis on the single-file simplicity)

Comment: I won't say it's specific to "MVC style of coding"; it's just what some folks brought to the field. For example, check what guy that created Marionette thinks about having models/model.js, collections/collection.js and crap like this. After all, you can decide how much your js files should contain and use grunt build to pack everything into single js file.

Comment: https://speakerdeck.com/derickbailey/scaling-backbone-dot-js-applications-with-marionette-dot-js
ou’ll learn why copying Ruby on Rails’ pattern of “Models”, “Views” and “Controllers” folder names is wrong for scaling JavaScript apps, and how to correct that .

Comment: Thanks I will check these resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: Codepen is a sandbox for testing, not app development.  Putting all your code in a single file may be convenient for a simple example, but once you have to scroll through thousands of lines of spaghetti code, you'll soon change your mind.  Putting your code into separate files, or modules, is *worth the trouble*; you can always minify before moving to a production environment.